# Can I find who is coming to my website using facebook open graph api

Tags: facebook, web, facebook-opengraph

In my website if i use the  open graph api can I track who is coming into my website
(I mean to say the person's Facebook profile Id) 
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can’t. You can only get the actual user if he has connected to your app first.